# Ambiguous implicit values

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, ambiguity

I've been thinking I understand scala implicits until recently faced strange problem.

In my application I have several domain classes

```
case class Foo(baz: String)
case class Bar(baz: String)
```

And a class that is able to construct domain object from a string. It could be subclassed to do real deserialization it doesn't matter.

```
class Reads[A] {
  def read(s: String): A = throw new Exception("not implemented")
}
```

Next, there are implicit deserializers

```
implicit val fooReads = new Reads[Foo]
implicit val barReads = new Reads[Bar]
```

And a helper to convert strings to one of domain classes

```
def convert[A](s: String)(implicit reads: Reads[A]): A = reads.read(s)
```

Unfortunatelly, when trying to use it

```
def f(s: String): Foo = convert(s)
```

I get compiler errors like

```
error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both value fooReads of type => Reads[Foo]
 and value barReads of type => Reads[Bar]
 match expected type Reads[A]
       def f(s: String): Foo = convert(s)
                                      ^
```

To me code seems simple and right. `Reads[Foo]` and `Reads[Bar]` is a completely different types, what is ambiguous about it?

The real code is much more complicated and uses `play.api.libs.json` but this simplified version is sufficient to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The ambiguity you're encountering in your example is that you didn't tell Scalac which one you wanted to use. You need to replace your code with

```
def f(s: String): Foo = convert[Foo](s)
```

in order for it to figure out which one to use. It can't infer from the return type of `f`. It needs to be explicit here.

**Response to comment**

Let me play devil's advocate here.

```
trait Foo
case class Bar(s: String) extends Foo
case class Baz(s: String) extends Foo

def f(s: String): Foo = convert(s)
```

which implicit does it use assuming there is one defined for both `Bar` and `Baz`? I'm sure there's more devilish corner cases out there but this one jumps out to me.

Comment: You're right, it fixes the problem, but imagine `convert` being implicit and `f` defined as `def f(s: String): Foo = s`. Is it impossible to accomplish? In theory, scala could infer `Foo` type from `f`'s return type, so why the error?

Comment: @lambdas Could it? `Foo` in that position is really `+Foo` so in theory, if `f` were passed as a function into some `def bar(f: String => Foo)` then anything extending `Foo` could be as well. Then your `convert[A]` would always try to infer to `Foo`? Even if you passed in a `def baz[A <: Foo](s: String): A` function? I don't know. These types of things keep me up at night.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you are making generic type A invariant. Instead this should be covariant. So this should be implemented as follows

```
case class Foo(baz: String)
case class Bar(baz: String)

// This `+` ↓ is the only difference  
class Reads[+A] {
  def read(s: String): A = throw new Exception("not implemented")
}

implicit val fooReads = new Reads[Foo]
implicit val barReads = new Reads[Bar]

def convert[A](s: String)(implicit reads: Reads[A]): A = reads.read(s)

def f(s: String): Foo = convert(s)
```

Please refer to http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/variances.html for more information.

Comment: please someone can explain why it works?